# Create UNIT tests in VS 2012/2013 is not including one of the class files

Tags: c#, unit-testing, visual-studio-2012, visual-studio-2013

I'm creating unit tests in 2012/2013 (Ultimate) and I think I'm sure that I've done everything that I should in order to get it to work.

setup:

visual studio windows form project

- create unit test project
- right click on a method in any class and choose create Unit tests
- wizard opens up and all of the classes are listed in there except for 1.
- this is the class that I'm actually concerned with (most concerned to unit test)

No matter what class I right click to start the wizard, my one class never shows up to put a tick beside and thus the class (unit test class) never gets created for it.

What am I missing?

Thanks!

Comment: Be more specific. Your question is open to a multitude of answers which will all be as good as each other. What do you want exactly?

Comment: @AaronToth Why can't you create your unit tests manually?

Comment: I downloaded the "Unit Test Generator" from the ALM Rangers.  Works like a charm.  I am writing them manually.  This just sets up the skeleton - consistent and well structured.  Thanks!

Comment: @WillMarcouiller - Just coming back to this now.  I'm am very confused on how you don't understand my question.  It hasn't changed, I just showed 2 others and they said "it looks like one of your classes is not getting picked up when you choose "Create Unit Tests".  I think it is pretty clear what the problem is, especially since another user said "Why can't you create it manually".  Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I downloaded an extension that would allow me to successfully right-click and auto generate a unit test.  This was in 2010 and now isn't in 2012/2013.  I enabled that menu in 2012 under customize - commands... etc and it worked.  In 2013.4 it doesn't.  The downloaded extension (Unit Test Generator) is working great.

Answer (score 1):

Is your class private? If so you can try to use InternalsVisibleToAttribute Class.

[http://www.oakwoodinsights.com/internalsvisbleto-attribute/][1]

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks for replying.  There are 4 classes in the project and they are all the same (private).

Comment: Check the link I posted. See if it fits your needs. Probably to access your private classes on Unit Testing you have to set the private methods to internal, and then add the InternalsVisibleToAttribute Class to the AssemblyInfo.cs of your project. Good luck.